# Jest keeps warning "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: node.js, jestjs, es6-modules, babel-jest

It looks like import modules errors.
This is my package.json settings, can anyone point me what am I missing ?
Thanks.

```
{
  "name": "prj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port 8080",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview --port 8000",
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "vue"],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
    }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.6",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.7",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.11",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.6.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.14",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.5.1",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-alpha.10"
  }
}
```

ExperimentalWarning: VM Modules is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
FAIL  src/tests/examples.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

......

Details:

/some/path/src/tests/examples.test.js:4
import HomePage from './src/views/HomePage.vue';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using webpack and had the same error that I fixed installing babel-core bridge:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0
```

I needed also the following one in jest.config.js:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
```

[Documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/installation/#using-vue-test-utils-with-jest-recommended)

Comment: Right, that is babel related problem. Reinstalled babel lib and it was fixed.

Comment: @WinstonSmith If this answer worked for you then you should accept it as the approved answer or suggest edits.